# CSS crop image height without changing its width

Tags: html, css, image

How can I fit picture into 400x460px container if I need the width to be exactly 400px and height crop to 460px? For example: If I have 400x470 px image I need to crop 10 px from the bottom. Image can't be smaller than 400x460, but can be bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a container with `overflow=hidden` for the image tag

html code:

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="./image.png" height="100%" alt="" />
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="./image.png" width="100%" alt="" />
</div>
```

if you want image size to fit on the height you need to add `height="100%"` or fit on width add `width="100%"`

CSS code:

```
.img-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 460px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `overflow: hidden;` in style of your image container